# Store and its lock file has been locked by another process: /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/store_lock

Tags: neo4j

what I did

```
neo4j console
```

(work fine)

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>

upon restarting I have message above.

I delete `/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/store_lock`

then I have

```
Externally locked: /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/neostore
```

Is there any way of cleaning lock ? (short of reinstalling)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can kill the java process and delete the store_lock file. It doesn't seem to harm the database integrity.

Comment: You should check though why the store_lock file did not get cleared on its own after a while - is this consistent?

Comment: I did kill the process but it immediately restarted itself. What should I do ?

Answer (score 13):

Killing the Java process and deleting the `store_lock` worked for me:

Found the lingering process,

```
ps aux | grep "org.neo4j.server"
```

killed it,

```
kill -9 <pid-of-neo4js-java-process>
```

and deleted

```
sudo rm /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/store_lock
```

[Allegedly](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/10420), just killing the lingering process may do the trick but I went ahead and deleted the lock anyway.

Comment: I killed the java process and the container stop. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

I found this question having same error message trying to import CSV using neo4j-admin tool.

In my case the problem was that I first launched neo4j server:

```
docker run -d --name testneo4j -p7474:7474 -p7687:7687 -v /path/to/neo4j/data:/data -v /path/to/neo4j/logs:/logs -v /path/to/neo4j/import:/var/lib/neo4j/import -v /path/to/neo4j/plugins:/plugins --env NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/test neo4j:latest
```

and then tried to launch import (CSV data files see [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/4.2/tutorial/neo4j-admin-import/#tutorial-neo4j-admin-import)):

```
docker exec -it testneo4j neo4j-admin import --nodes=Movies=import/movies.csv --nodes=Actors=import/actors.csv --relationships=ACTED_IN=import/roles.csv
```

This leads to lock error since server acquires database lock and neo4j-admin is independent tool which needs to acquire database lock too. Kills, lock file removals and sudos didn't work for me.

What helped:

1. `docker run --rm ... neo4j:latest neo4j-admin ...` - this performs one-shot import into empty database. No dead container remains, only imported data in external volume. (Note the command fails if db is not empty.) The point is, the Docker entrypoint starts server unless CMD in [Dockerfile](https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j/blob/master/docker-image-src/4.2/Dockerfile) is [overriden](https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j/blob/master/docker-image-src/4.2/docker-entrypoint.sh#L499).
2. `docker run -d ... neo4j:latest` - this runs neo4j server