# Can't startup neo4j and log error: "Unable to read store format: Externally locked"

Tags: neo4j

I'm using neo4j 3.3.4 and it had run OK in a long time, but after the machine reboot, neo4j can't startup, in the log have the following message:
Unable to read store format: Externally locked: /home/ap/nas/neo4j/2/neo4j-enterprise-3.3.4/data/databases/graph.db/neostore

I had tried to remove "store_lock" file, but it's seems useless.
How can I resolve the problem?

this is the error info about neo4j.log and debug.log:

```
debug.log:
2018-08-20 11:31:03.303+0800 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] --- INITIALIZED diagnostics END ---
2018-08-20 11:31:03.603+0800 INFO [o.n.b.v.r.WorkerFactory] Bolt Server extension loaded.
2018-08-20 11:31:03.606+0800 INFO [o.n.b.v.r.WorkerFactory] Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.
2018-08-20 11:31:03.623+0800 INFO [o.n.m.MetricsExtension] Initiating metrics...
2018-08-20 11:31:03.875+0800 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.f.RecordFormatSelector] Unable to read store format: Externally locked: /home/ap/nas/neo4j/2/neo4j-enterprise-3.3.4/data/databases/graph.db/neostore
2018-08-20 11:31:03.903+0800 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.f.RecordFormatSelector] Selected format 'RecordFormat:StandardV3_2[v0.A.8]' for the new store
2018-08-20 11:31:03.960+0800 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.f.RecordFormatSelector] Unable to read store format: Externally locked: /home/ap/nas/neo4j/2/neo4j-enterprise-3.3.4/data/databases/graph.db/neostore
2018-08-20 11:31:03.990+0800 WARN [o.n.k.NeoStoreDataSource] Exception occurred while setting up store modules. Attempting to close things down. org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.FileLockException: Externally locked: /home/ap/nas/neo4j/2/neo4j-enterprise-3.3.4/data/databases/graph.db/neostore
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.UnderlyingStorageException: org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.FileLockException: Externally locked: /home/ap/nas/neo4j/2/neo4j-enterprise-3.3.4/data/databases/graph.db/neostore
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.verifyRecordFormat(NeoStores.java:212)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.<init>(NeoStores.java:144)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.openNeoStores(StoreFactory.java:160)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.openAllNeoStores(StoreFactory.java:124)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.<init>(RecordStorageEngine.java:200)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.buildStorageEngine(NeoStoreDataSource.java:587)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:449)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:100)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:207)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.<init>(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.java:50)
        at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.OpenEnterpriseNeoServer.lambda$static$1(OpenEnterpriseNeoServer.java:69)
        at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:88)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:212)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:111)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:79)
        at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.OpenEnterpriseEntryPoint.main(OpenEnterpriseEntryPoint.java:36)
Caused by: org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.FileLockException: Externally locked: /home/ap/nas/neo4j/2/neo4j-enterprise-3.3.4/data/databases/graph.db/neostore
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.SingleFilePageSwapper.acquireLock(SingleFilePageSwapper.java:208)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.SingleFilePageSwapper.<init>(SingleFilePageSwapper.java:159)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.SingleFilePageSwapperFactory.createPageSwapper(SingleFilePageSwapperFactory.java:71)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPagedFile.<init>(MuninnPagedFile.java:147)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.map(MuninnPageCache.java:340)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.MetaDataStore.getRecord(MetaDataStore.java:290)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.verifyRecordFormat(NeoStores.java:193)
        ... 21 more
2018-08-20 11:31:03.996+0800 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] --- STOPPING diagnostics START ---
2018-08-20 11:31:03.997+0800 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] High Availability diagnostics
Member state:PENDING
State machines:
   AtomicBroadcastMessage:start
   AcceptorMessage:start
   ProposerMessage:start
   LearnerMessage:start
   HeartbeatMessage:start
   ElectionMessage:start
   SnapshotMessage:start
   ClusterMessage:start
Current timeouts:

2018-08-20 11:31:03.997+0800 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] --- STOPPING diagnostics END ---
2018-08-20 11:31:04.007+0800 INFO [o.n.k.i.f.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory] Shutdown started
2018-08-20 11:31:04.019+0800 INFO [o.n.k.c.Config] Setting changed: 'dbms.logs.query.enabled' changed from 'true' to 'false'


neo4j.log:
2018-08-20 11:31:02.033+0800 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.3.4 ========
2018-08-20 11:31:02.081+0800 INFO  Starting...
2018-08-20 11:31:03.184+0800 INFO  Write transactions to database disabled
2018-08-20 11:31:03.604+0800 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.
2018-08-20 11:31:03.621+0800 INFO  Initiating metrics...
2018-08-20 11:31:04.052+0800 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@18e7143f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Externally locked: /home/ap/nas/neo4j/2/neo4j-enterprise-3.3.4/data/databases/graph.db/neostore". Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@18e7143f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Externally locked: /home/ap/nas/neo4j/2/neo4j-enterprise-3.3.4/data/databases/graph.db/neostore".
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@18e7143f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Externally locked: /home/ap/nas/neo4j/2/neo4j-enterprise-3.3.4/data/databases/graph.db/neostore".
        at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:220)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:111)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:79)
        at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.OpenEnterpriseEntryPoint.main(OpenEnterpriseEntryPoint.java:36)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@18e7143f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Externally locked: /home/ap/nas/neo4j/2/neo4j-enterprise-3.3.4/data/databases/graph.db/neostore".
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:212)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /home/ap/nas/neo4j/2/neo4j-enterprise-3.3.4/data/databases/graph.db
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:211)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.<init>(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.java:50)
        at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.OpenEnterpriseNeoServer.lambda$static$1(OpenEnterpriseNeoServer.java:69)
        at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:88)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@6e9319f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Externally locked: /home/ap/nas/neo4j/2/neo4j-enterprise-3.3.4/data/databases/graph.db/neostore".
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:100)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:207)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.UnderlyingStorageException: org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.FileLockException: Externally locked: /home/ap/nas/neo4j/2/neo4j-enterprise-3.3.4/data/databases/graph.db/neostore
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.verifyRecordFormat(NeoStores.java:212)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.<init>(NeoStores.java:144)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.openNeoStores(StoreFactory.java:160)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.openAllNeoStores(StoreFactory.java:124)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.<init>(RecordStorageEngine.java:200)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.buildStorageEngine(NeoStoreDataSource.java:587)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:449)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.FileLockException: Externally locked: /home/ap/nas/neo4j/2/neo4j-enterprise-3.3.4/data/databases/graph.db/neostore
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.SingleFilePageSwapper.acquireLock(SingleFilePageSwapper.java:208)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.SingleFilePageSwapper.<init>(SingleFilePageSwapper.java:159)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.SingleFilePageSwapperFactory.createPageSwapper(SingleFilePageSwapperFactory.java:71)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPagedFile.<init>(MuninnPagedFile.java:147)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.map(MuninnPageCache.java:340)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.MetaDataStore.getRecord(MetaDataStore.java:290)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.verifyRecordFormat(NeoStores.java:193)
        ... 21 more
2018-08-20 11:31:04.053+0800 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
```

Comment: Maybe your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44757181/store-and-its-lock-file-has-been-locked-by-another-process-var-lib-neo4j-data

Comment: I had try that method but it's not working, in my machine there are no Java thread and I have remove the  lock file. but  it's useless.

Comment: that  thread's error log also difference with me, my error information is "Unable to read store format: Externally locked"，that  thread is lock by other process